# How to clear navigation history in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I created a login / signup page in my react-native app...I would like to prevent users from going back to that page after successful login

In nativescript, I do that by setting `clearHistory: true` when navigating
How can I do that in react-native

My navigation code is like this:

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('home screen', { email: email}
```

Thank you

Comment: Try to use `navigation.replace` instead of `navigation.navigate` to switch the route instead of pushing it.

Comment: As @Tj3n said you can use `navigation.replace` or another way is to create two seperate Navigators. First one for `Authentication` and second for for all `app contents`

Comment: you should you SwitchNavigator with StackNavigator. keep login screen with SwtichNavigator and rest of the Screens with StackNavigator and use StackNavigator as one Screen in SwtichNavigator .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked

`navigation.replace('homescreen', {email : email})`

Answer (score 11):

If you're using `react-navigation` there is a method [`popToTop`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#poptotop). This should clear your navigation stack, if `'home screen'` isn't your app's first screen, you can `navigate` later:

```js
this.props.navigation.popToTop();
this.props.navigation.navigate('home screen', { email: email};
```

Answer (score 3):

In react navigation version 6

```js
import { useNavigation, CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

    CommonActions.reset({
         index: 1,
         routes: [{ name: 'name of the screen that you wanna be in' }],       
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

this works well for me.

```
navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [{ name: 'Home' }],
  })
);
```